# Ionic - crosswalk plugin only on old android versions

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am building an android app with ionic 1, which is ran only on my own devices.

For old android versions (<5) i need the crosswalk plugin for performance reasons. Otherwise my app is unusable.

However, as crosswalk is depreciated for newer versions of android, that have a good native browser built in, I would like *not* to use crosswalk on devices with those newer android versions.

Is there a way to implement this in ionic's config.xml or by any other means ?

Answer (score 1):

No, There is not other option I also used it before but the apk size is too large. But it's ok to use your ionic app without crosswalk most of devices today are eligible to run ionic projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case the apk size is not a problem: devices are fully dedicated to my app. If there is really no other option, I'll create two separate builds for old and new devices.